# A-frame gltf points at camera angle

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, virtual-reality, webvr

I'm wondering how it's possible using A-frame (aframe.io) to rotate a gltf model constantly so it's always facing the position the camera is looking at. for example. If I'm looking straight ahead at 0 degrees, the gltf is also pointing at 0 degrees. If I turn the camera to face 90 degrees, the gltf turns to 9 degrees. I've already tried creating a variable and setting the camera angle to that variable and setting the `rotation` property to the variable but been able to figure out how to capture the camera angle as a variable and set the `rotation` property of gltf to the variable. Ideally, I would want to figure out how I can create something like this:

```
<script>
var rotate;
var rotate = camera angle;
</script>
<a-gltf-model src="" position="0 0 0" rotation="var rotate" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1"></a-gltf-model>
```

Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Since A-frame is based on Three.js, you could use the `lookAt` method of Object3D.
Here is a npm package for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-look-at-component

Comment: It worked but a little too well, the game I'm creating is an online game and I want to be looking at the direction the camera is looking at so each person is represented by a gltf that turns accordingly to the direction the user is facing. Currently, the gltfs are always looking at another online player, not in the direction my camera is pointing. Do you know a way to fix this?